How do I insert a table by tag into a docx using python?
I have a problem. I want to replace the {{ table }} tag with a table (at least a regular one, rows =2, cols=2). I would be very grateful if there is a solution to this problem.
Here is an excerpt of a docx document with a replaceable tag {{ table }}


The second screenshot shows the current code for replacing tags

PS.Method .addTable() for the Document() object from the docx library adds only to the end of the file. Is it possible to replace the tag in the middle of a text document?
